# Matlab: Error using fastinsert. 1st fastinsert works, subsequent ones do not

Tags: sql-server, matlab

I'm trying to insert data from Matlab (R2012b) to a MS SQL Server (2008R2) using `fastinsert()` of the database toolbox:

```
fastinsert(conn, tableNm, inC(:,1), inC(:,2));
```

`isconnection(conn)` returns true and is closed after fastinsert, `tableNm` and `inC` are in the right format for my database.

If I run this for the first time, it works correct and the data is inserted in the database. If I run it another time in the same Matlab session I get the following error:

```
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Parameter.setValue(Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/JDBCType;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/JavaType;Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/StreamSetterArgs;Ljava/util/Calendar;Ljava/lang/Integer;Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection;)V

at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:723)

at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setDouble(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:866)
```

Two fields of `tableNm` are datatime, the others are floats but this is not a problem in my succesful insertion. If I restart Matlab and run it again, it will work once and then stop working. The database can accept duplicate records.

Can anyone explain what I did wrong and how to make this work?

Edit: `exec(conn, query)` does work
Edit: This error happens now very infrequently and is not reproducable, the same data sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: What format are you providing the `datetime` values in? Are they char/cellstr strings or double datenums or something else? Are you re-running it on the same `conn` object or a newly created one? Can you provide code showing the creation of `conn` and `fastinsert` calls for both insertions?

Comment: Oh, and which version of the SQL Server JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Does it also go wrong the second time if you first try this: `fastinsert(conn, tableNm, inC(1,1), inC(1,2))` and then this: `fastinsert(conn, tableNm, inC(2,1), inC(2,2))`? If not you may be violating some uniqueness or other constraints with your original attempt.